# How to import a single file from CVS into project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, cvs

I'm trying to copy a single file from CVS into a new project that I created, but when you right click on the file in CVS it doens't have the option to check the file out. If I right click on a folder in CVS however, I can check out an entire folder to my project. How can I copy just a single file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder-level "Check Out" action establishes linkage between the content of a local folder and the repository. You can then work in connected mode with change tracking etc. CVS tracks this linkage at folder level. It doesn't support single-file linkage.

Perhaps you don't care about this linkage and just want to retrieve a file from the repository. To do that, double-click on the file in the CVS Repositories view. Once the file opens in an editor, save it wherever you'd like.

Comment: If I understand correctly, CVS by itself can handle the OP's use case just fine. It is the Eclipse Plugin that can only maintain the linkage at the folder level. Either way, the only use case covered by the current implementation is to check out an entire folder.

Answer (score 2):

```
cvs co <your_project>/path/to/file_you_are_interested_in
```

Comment: I'm using the eclipse interface. I have no idea how to even get to the command line.

Comment: Oh OK. I do not think you can do that using eclipse's cvs plug in.If all that you are interested is in that file. Check the project out somewhere else and copy over the file to your source tree.

Comment: So there's no way to move a single file, only a folder? That just seems like the dumbest thing ever. Why would they intentionally do that?

Comment: @Catfish Do you *really* think whoever implemented the CVS plugin is dumb?

Comment: No, but i'm saying that seems like a dumb thing not to allow you to check out a single file, but to check out an entire folder.